# Determining the input capacitance for a SMPS

Tags: capacitor, switch-mode-power-supply, decoupling-capacitor, ripple-current

I'm attempting to layout a SMPS using the [LTC3703](http://cds.linear.com/docs/en/datasheet/3703fc.pdf) chip, however the datasheet doesn't talk about the AMOUNT of input capacitance, just that it be low esr.  However, it does talk about "bulk capacitance".

What I'm not sure about is how I figure out how much total capacitance I need.  Is there a relationship between ripple current and capacitance?

Comment: It would difficult to calculate, especially since there is dependent on the external mosfet. So the datasheet tells you to minimize esr, not that it is low. If you want more efficiency, then minimize the esr in the input cap. Some things are dependent on implementation and easier to measure than calculate.

Comment: Can someone explain why this question is put on hold?  I got a good answer and it was well understood by at least one member of this community.  The term "input capacitance" for a SMPS isn't vague or unclear, it is very specific.

Comment: @laptop2d:  I guess I'm confused, a 10pF ceramic cap will have a very very low ESR, but I somehow doubt that will work.    How do I measure this?  What does the bulk capacitance help with?  Also, why did you vote to put on hold?  What is unclear here?

Comment: the question is confusing because it can be answered in the datasheet. I personally didn't put it on hold, but I did vote to close because: the question is unclear because there is no way to find the ripple current without knowing exactly what your setup is, you would need to provide a schematic and a block diagram of your setup and the ripple would have to be measured, and at the end of the day it would be easier just to put in capacitors yourself and measure it. The rule of thumb from the datasheet is the lower esr the better.

Comment: It might be good to use two caps, a big one and a small one (such as the 10pf cap) to take advantage of the esr differences.

Comment: It can't be answered in the datasheet.  Any information on the bulk capacitance at the input isn't mentioned.  It is fairly clear that a 10pF cap won't be enough, but it isn't clear how you find out how much IS enough.  While it would be nice to have my work done for me (add a schematic and someone can tell me how much bulk capacitance I need), I would rather have a more general theoretical understanding of the input capacitance for switchmode power supplies.

Comment: How much ripple is acceptable for your application? How much ripple does the SMPS source PSU in your application output (or is it a battery)? At what frequencies (did they provide a frequency graph)? This information is critical for answering the question.

Comment: The datasheet does talk about using two caps, a low ESR ceramic to offset the ripple current for a higher ESR bulk capacitor.

Comment: "How much ripple is acceptable for your application?" output ripple?  or input ripple?  I don't know how much input ripple is acceptable (should I just consider this to be the "dropout" of the SMPS?)  How much output ripple though is controlled by the output capacitor and inductor I would believe.  I have found [this](http://www.ti.com.cn/cn/lit/an/slta055/slta055.pdf) article, and will be writing up my own answer to this question when I get the time.  The bulk capacitance calculations that they are mentioning have nothing to do with frequency.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of things to keep in mind when selecting input capacitors.  If the input caps are electrolytic, you must check the ripple current to be sure you're not exceeding the rating.  Then, you should check the amount of ripple voltage you will be inducing on the input voltage and make sure you have enough capacitance for your requirement.  Typically you should have enough capacitance to keep the input ripple voltage below 5%.

For ceramic capacitors the ESR is low enough that you don't need to worry about the ripple current rating, so target enough capacitance to keep the input ripple voltage where you want it.  Be sure to take the voltage and temperature derating of the caps in mind since ceramic caps with high volumetric efficiency can have terrible derating characteristics with applied DC voltage and temperature.

This is all especially important on the input to a buck converter because the input current is discontinuous, resulting in lots of input ripple current. (Likewise on the output of a boost converter.)

Here's a link to an article that discusses the equations and specifics of how to select the capacitors and capacitance:

[Selecting input capacitors](http://www.eetimes.com/document.asp?doc_id=1273212)

Comment: How do I figure out what the input ripple voltage is? (nevermind... it looks like the article you linked mentions that.)